# Android to PHP error- Unidentified Index

Tags: php, android

when sending data to a php server through android I cam across this error: "Notice: Undefined index: IT in C:\xampp\htdocs\hello.php on line 4". After a few hours of messing around with it I can't solve my issue.

hello.php :

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
mysql_select_db("mmo");
$r=mysql_query("update players set X = '".$_REQUEST['IT']."' where 22=22");
if(!$r)
echo "Error in query: ".mysql_error();
mysql_close();
header('Refresh: 0.01; URL=http://localhost/hello.php');
?>
```

update method in android:

```
public void UpdateSeverWithPlayer()
{List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IT","3"));
try{
     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/hello.php");
     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
     is = entity.getContent();
     }catch(Exception e){
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
    }}
```

I am working on the android emulator and do have the internet permission. As always help is greatly appreciated.
EDIT 1: It appears the issue is in the android and not the php code.

Comment: try print_r($_POST) to see what you're getting posted.  (Note: use $_POST and not $_REQUEST as it's safer - you should also check the function mysql_real_escape_string() when you get chance too ;) )

Comment: Hi, it seems print_r($_POST) returns Array ( ), thanks all for looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not sending your query string propertly somehow, so there is no `$_REQUEST['IT']` on the PHP side. do a `var_dump($_REQUEST)` to see what's coming through. Or better yet, don't use $_REQUEST. It's somewhat insecure. Better use the superglobal directly related to your HTTP method, _GET or _POST.

As well, the `Refresh` header is non-standard. it'll work, but you shouldn't depend on it. An HTTP level redirect uses the Location: header. Refresh: is a non-standard old-school Netscape extension.

Comment: var_dump($_REQUEST) returns array(0) { }

Comment: Then you've got no query parameters/form values being sent, which means the error is android-side.

Comment: No idea, I'm not an android dev.

Comment: I'll upvote for the help, but I'm going to wait till I solve the problem before accepting. Thank you.